# Bash script, echo is wrapping when I don't want it to

Tags: bash, curl

I have a bash script wrapping a pair of `curl`s, piped through some other builtins. I want to print the result of each curl, and then parse the results and emit a third line that contains additional information. The final output should look like:

```
https://e.thingzz.com/eqvjzc23xqo2s
https://e.thingzz.com/o7jlafrot2fok
https://e.thingzz.com/c/eqvjzc23xqo2s/o7jlafrot2fok
```

Instead, it looks like:

```
https://e.thingzz.com/eqvjzc23xqo2s
https://e.thingzz.com/o7jlafrot2fok
/o7jlafrot2fokv.com/c/eqvjzc23xqo2s
```

For some reason, it's wrapping at the exact length of the prior two lines.

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function myCurl()
{
    curl ... | ... | ... 
    #omitted, results in printing a url like 'https://e.thingzz.com/UUID' 
}

# param validation omitted
URL1=$(myCurl "${1}")
URL2=$(myCurl "${2}")
# print both URLs
echo $URL1
echo $URL2

# Parse URLs to get ID at end
# I've also tried using `cut`, in case there were invisible characters?
# I don't really know what I'm talking about.
URLID1=$(echo $URL1 | awk -F 'https://thing.com/' '{print $2}')
URLID2=$(echo $URL2 | awk -F 'https://thing.com/' '{print $2}')

# Doesn't work. Looks like:
# /o7jlafrot2fokv.com/c/eqvjzc23xqo2s
echo https://thing.com/c/${URLID1}/${URLID2}
# Proves I can echo something longer
echo doneaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
# Also wraps, exactly like the `echo` version
echo $URLID1 $URLID2 | awk '{ printf "https://thing.com/c/%s/%s", $1, $2 }'
```

I am far from a bash expert, and have no idea what's going on here. I've tried variations on this from the command line (not from invoking a script), and it works. I'm really just at a loss here.

**EDIT:** I replaced SCANID1 with URLID1 (and for 2 as well). They were copy-paste errors.

Comment: I suspect the data contains CRLF line endings and the exactness of the lengths is mostly coincidence.

Comment: Where do `SCANID1` and `SCANID2` come from. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: @chepner that was a copy-paste error. Those should be `URLID1` and `URLID2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jonathan Leffler already remarked in a comment, the most likely explanation is the presence of Windows (CRLF) line endings in the data. Unix uses LF line endings. On a terminal, a CR character moves the cursor to the beginning of the line without moving it to the next line. For example, if you run

```
printf '%s\r%s\n' wibble foo
```

you'll see `fooble` because `wibble` gets displayed, then the cursor moves to the beginning of the line and `foo` overwrites the beginning of `wibble`.

Your script doesn't completely match your sample output, but it seems that the line

```
echo https://thing.com/c/${SCANID1}/${SCANID2}
```

produces output that has a slash and the value of `SCANID2` at the beginning of the line. That's happening because the value of `SCANID1` ends with a CR character.

To make your script robust against Windows line endings, remove any CR character, or at least any CR character at the end of a line (if you have CR characters in other places, you have other problems with your data). In bash, `"${var%$'\r'}"` gives the value of `var` minus the trailing CR if the value ends with a CR, and gives the value unchanged if it doesn't end with a CR.

I recommend stripping the CRs early to avoid any problem:

```
URL1=$(myCurl "${1}"); URL1=${URL1%$'\r'}
URL2=$(myCurl "${2}"); URL2=${URL2%$'\r'}
```

(You can't combine the command substitution and the truncation in a single assignment.)

But you could also do it at the awk stage:

```
SCANID1=$(echo "$URL1" | awk -F 'https://thing.com/' '{print sub("\r", "", $2)}')
```

Mind you, there's no need to invoke awk here.

```
SCANID1=${URL1#*https://*/}
```

Comment: `URL1=$(myCurl "${1}"); URL1=${URL1%$'\r'}` worked perfectly. Thank you!